# How to prevent auto image rotatation in imageview?

Tags: android, android-imageview, google-drive-android-api, image-rotation, autorotate

I am struggling with the image auto rotation into image view.

**Issue no. 1**

As per my observation, if image is rotated to any angle then at time of displaying image into imageview, android rotate that image as per the rotation angle.

Lets say.. if image is rotated to 180 degree CW then android re-rotate image to 180 degree to display image properly. I don't want android rotate image.

Even gallery showing that image as it is. Device gallery is not making any kind of manipulation at time of displaying images.

**Issue no. 2**
Another issue with Samsung devices. Samsung default capture angle is landscape. Means if I capture any photo in landscape mode image rotation will be 0. But If I capture image in portrait mode image rotation value will be 90. Problem start here. Now if try to display that portrait image android image view rotate that image to 90 degree. So image will be displayed in horizontally instead of vertically.

As a solution, I can read rotation degree from image and make calculation before displaying.

**Issue no. 3**

But when user pick image from Google drive, I will not have metadata of the selected image. So without it how can I make decision that image should rotate to this much degree.

I am expecting solution for below issues.

1. How to handle rotation for Samsung devices?
2. How to get rotation value from image selected from google drive?
3. Calculation to rotate image?
4. Any way to say android to don't  rotate image?

Comment: refer this link you will find your solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45168025/7765499

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [ExifInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) . There's a support version and a good description [link](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/introducing-the-exifinterface-support-library.html)

I'm not sure there's any way to avoid auto rotation but below there's sample code for detecting image rotation and setting the correct one. Hope this helps.

```
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(path);
            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            switch (orientation) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
                    matrix.setScale(-1, 1);
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    matrix.setRotate(180);
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL:
                    matrix.setRotate(180);
                    matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSPOSE:
                    matrix.setRotate(90);
                    matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    matrix.setRotate(90);
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSVERSE:
                    matrix.setRotate(-90);
                    matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    matrix.setRotate(-90);
                    break;
            }
```